# Can't pass an Input layer into tf.keras.Model()

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
input_tensor = Input(shape = (10,))
tf.keras.Model(inputs = input_tensor)
```

```
    TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'Inputs')
```

I am using tensorflow 2.0.0 from anaconda's package.  This error occurs when assign value to outputs also. I tried input instead of outputs. But nothing work. Mainly, I want to be able to pass a list of input layers with one input layer accepting a sample weight.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily, you have an extra bracket.
Regarding the problem, `tf.keras` only allows ***both*** inputs and outputs for instantiating a model.

So, if you'd (and I really don't know why) want to create a model with only this tensor, then you should do

```
tf.keras.Model(inputs = input_tensor, outputs = input_tensor)
```

Hope this helped!